# How can I view the first 10 elements of my array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array (`$keys`) in my code, where I only want to show the first 10 elements. I tried a foreach loop, but it just display all elements.

Instead of:

```
"72.4x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx",
```

I want to view them like this:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx
yyy.yyy.yyy
//etc.


for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++); {
    return $keys;
}
```

Comment: use `<br />` instead of `,`?

Comment: Do you want to show the first 10 elements now or do you just want to separate each value with a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array looks like this:

```
$array = array("72.4x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx","72.4x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx","72.4x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx","72.4x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx","90.18x.xxx.xxx","177.9x.xxx.xxx");
```

Use `implode()` and `array_chunk()` with a `<br />`

```
$topTen =   array_chunk($array,10);
echo implode("<br />".PHP_EOL,$topTen[0]);
```

**Gives you (display):**

```
72.4x.xxx.xxx
90.18x.xxx.xxx
177.9x.xxx.xxx
72.4x.xxx.xxx
90.18x.xxx.xxx
177.9x.xxx.xxx
72.4x.xxx.xxx
90.18x.xxx.xxx
177.9x.xxx.xxx
72.4x.xxx.xxx
```

**Gives you (source):**

```
72.4x.xxx.xxx<br />
90.18x.xxx.xxx<br />
177.9x.xxx.xxx<br />
72.4x.xxx.xxx<br />
90.18x.xxx.xxx<br />
177.9x.xxx.xxx<br />
72.4x.xxx.xxx<br />
90.18x.xxx.xxx<br />
177.9x.xxx.xxx<br />
72.4x.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: No problem, I am not sure if you saw my revision, this will do the top 10, just change the second value in the `array_chunk` to get less or more into the list

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` behind your for loop. If you `return` something in the loop it will run only once and return the array `$keys`

If you want to to this in a loop for some reason, maybe a break after x elements or something you can try the code below.

You can break the loop with [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php): `if( $i == 10 ) break;//$i is you index count`

```
$keys = array(
    "72.4x.xxx.xxx",
    "90.18x.xxx.xxx",
    "177.9x.xxx.xxx",
);

$output = "";
for ($i = 0; ( $i < count($keys) ); $i++)
{
    // how many elements you want to show? i.e. 10
    if( $i == 10 ) break;
    $output .= $keys[$i]."<br>";// line break \n or html <br>
}
echo $output;

// i would prefer the foreach
$output = "";
// add index
foreach( $keys as $index => $key )
{
    // how many elements you want to show? i.e. 10
    if( $index == 10 ) break;
    $output .= $key."<br>";// line break \n or html <br>
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: thanks this works perfect :) can you say me how i can say the for loop that i just want the first 10?

Comment: this works fine :) but my problem is.. all this is in my Controller - this works perfect with the break.. but i'm giving this variable to my view ( in laravel ) 

        return view('/domains/data', [       
                  'topTenIp' => $topTenIp,      
     ]);

and my view doesnt work with the output like want it..

72.46.xxx.xxx<br>90.xxx.xxx<br>177.xxx.xxx<br>85.xxx.xxxx<br>

this is what my view gives me and in google i cant fint a solution for this

Comment: I don't have a clue about you view, but can you try this: `return view('/domains/data', [ 'topTenIp' => $topTenIp, ])->render();` ?

Comment: how does you view look like and what is the exactly output?

Comment: Possibly you can try `{{ $topTenIp }}` instead of just `$topTenIp`